# Why is the following tcl script for NS2 gives error for procedure implementation?

Tags: tcl, ns2

I am very naive to NS2 use and was trying to implement CBR over UDP in NS2 . I wrote the following code:

```
set ns [new Simulator]
set tracefile [open out.tr w]
$ns trace-all $tracefile
set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

#should be "proc name args body"
#while executing
#"proc finish {}"

proc finish {}
{
global ns tracefile nf
    $ns flush-trace
    close $nf
    close $tracefile
    exec nam out.nam &
    exit 0
}
set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
$ns simplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail
set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n0 $udp0
set cbr[new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr attach-agent $udp0
set null0 [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n1 $null0
$ns connect $udp0 $null0
$ns at 1.0 "$cbr start"
$ns at 3.0 "finish"
$ns run
```

The error being shown is commented above the proc finish procedure. I tried to look for errors but couldn't find one. What I have done is written this as a Tcl script and for doing ns filename.tcl to run .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tcl *as a language* treats newline as being significant; it marks the end of a sequence of words that form a command invocation. Because `proc` is actually just a normal Tcl command (that happens to create commands using a script as implementation) and not some special syntax, if you do:

```
proc finish {}
```

Then you are supplying `proc` with one fewer arguments than it needs according to its definition. At that point, it complains, and that complaint is what you have observed. (`proc` does not know that you've decided to put a word that you want used as the script body on the next line; that's a level of smartness that Tcl explicitly eschews as a matter of policy, in that Tcl has no real special syntactic forms at all.)

The way to fix this is to write your code using [“one true brace” style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS), which Tcl strongly favors:

```
proc finish {} {
    # put the body in here
}
```

Failing that, you *can* use backslashes to write things differently:

```
proc finish {} \
{
    # body...
}
```

However, hardly any Tclers seem to favor that one. (After all, it requires more typing.)

Comment: The same applies to `if {...} then {...} else {...}`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes, and `while {…} {…}` and `for …` and … well, everything.